# Pandas creating multiple new columns at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have panda dataframe with the fields:

- A,B,C,D,E,F till Z

I want to create new fields:

- B/Z, C/Z, D/Z, E/Z till Y/Z

Is there a code in pandas to do this once without doing it repeatedly for each new field?

Comment: Can you explain more your logic? e.g. why `A,F` is missing in output? And why `F till Z`  is changed to `E/Z till Y/Z` ?

Comment: I just use these field names as an example.
Imagine A is the location identifier.
Fields B to Y are some numbers of observations.
Field Z is the number of population.
I just wanted the ratios from B/Z to Y/Z. I hope this is clear?

Answer (score 1):

You can select columns by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and indexing - e.g. `1:-1` for get all columns without first and last, divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[4,3,2,2,4,5],
         'Z':[5,3,6,9,2,4],

})

df = df.join(df.iloc[:, 1:-1].div(df['Z'], axis=0).add_suffix('/Z'))
```

Or remove columns by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.join(df.drop(['A','Z'], axis=1).div(df['Z'], axis=0).add_suffix('/Z'))
```

---

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  Z       B/Z       C/Z       D/Z
0  a  4  7  4  5  0.800000  1.400000  0.800000
1  b  5  8  3  3  1.666667  2.666667  1.000000
2  c  4  9  2  6  0.666667  1.500000  0.333333
3  d  5  4  2  9  0.555556  0.444444  0.222222
4  e  5  2  4  2  2.500000  1.000000  2.000000
5  f  4  3  5  4  1.000000  0.750000  1.250000
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks for all your helps!